# Shopify Script - Get a free X product when you spend Y amount

Tags: ruby, shopify, liquid

I'm searching all over the internet for a solution, and I hope you guys help me with that.
I want to do a shopify script that automatically add a specific free product if cart is over a specific amount (100$ for ex).
All i've find online is X% discount if cart is over $Y, but I want to add an existing product.
Is there a way to do it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sometimes you need to actually write some code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: didn't use any because i didn't find any.. and unfortunately i don't know ruby :/

Comment: You can't expect to build a custom application by blindly copy+pasting exact solutions off the internet! StackOverflow is not a free code writing service; you need to show some attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Comment: You should also clarify if you need this to be a rule, or just a suggestion. As the answer from Up at Five suggests you can use the Ajax API to play with cart contents, but then, so can the customer. So anyone can do anything with your cart. If for example you have a free product, I could load 500 in my cart and checkout, regardless of the amount of other products. So you have to be careful to specify your actual needs. No code at StackOverflow will help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the shopify Ajax API (https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api).

With this API you can make a request to the cart `GET /cart.js` and get back the `total_price`. You can write some logic to say if that is > 100$ then post X product.

You can post a product to the cart with the Ajax API as well `POST /cart/add.js`

We wrote a little post on adding products to the cart with the Ajax API if you want to reference an example ajax request http://www.codeshopify.com/blog_posts/adding-to-cart-with-ajax